# Next auth `useSession` must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider /> error after upgrade to next 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I upgraded my next JS version from next 13.0 to 13.4 and now the Next auth is not functioning properly. before the upgrade i created an `AuthProvider.js` file in the root of the app dir. in this i wrapped the children with `SessionProvider` and then inside `layout.js` from the root i wrapped everything with the AuthProvider i created. and this works.

`AuthProvider.js`

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      <ChakraProvider>
        {/* <SkeletonTheme baseColor="#B3B3B3" highlightColor="#BCBCBC"> */}
        {children}
        {/* </SkeletonTheme> */}
      </ChakraProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

`app/layout.js`

```
<html>
      <head />
      <body className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <AuthProvider>
          <NextTopLoader color="#008080" showSpinner={false} />
          {children}
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
```

but now when i upgrade to next 13.4 and wherever i use the session it throws an error `Error: [next-auth]:` useSession `must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider />` and the error points to the component i used the session in?

why is this happening and how can i fix this?

i'm using next_auth version : ^4.18.8

Comment: Is the session provider component a client side or server side component?

Comment: @FabioNettis it is client side

Answer (score 0):

The error basically says that whatever the session component is providing cannot be found, be it context etc. Depending on where you trying to access the `useSession` hook you may still be on the server. Try adding an explicit `"use client";` directive at the top of your file.

##### Inside your layout file

```
<html>
  <head />
  <body className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
    <AuthProvider>
      <NextTopLoader color="#008080" showSpinner="{false}" />
      {children}
    </AuthProvider>
  </body>
</html>
```

##### Inside your component

```
"use client";

const MyConsumerComponent = () => {
  const session = useSession();
  return <></>;
}
```

If that does not work try dynamically importing your component skipping the server side rendering with `next/dynamic`. Here is an example:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const MyConsumerComponent = dynamic(() => import("./MyConsumerComponent"), {
  ssr: false,
});

const MyParentComponent = () => {
  return <MyConsumerComponent />;
}
```